# PhoneGap build iOS xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

Tags: cordova, cocoapods, phonegap-build, cordova-ios

I'm working on creating an application that uses both PhoneGap to build the app and CocoaPods to manage external dependencies. Up front, this works fine -- PhoneGap generates the project on the first `phonegap install ios`, and CocoaPods correctly takes that generated project and generates an xcworkspace.

Unfortunately, subsequent calls to `phonegap build ios` fail because they're trying to build the xcodeproj still, which has dependencies that are only available through the xcworkspace.

To me, it seems like this would be a common problem, as they both seem to be fairly common tools for this iOS development, but I haven't been able to find anyone having similar issues.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. For now i'm going to try to copy the cordova.js file into my www folder manually, but I would really love it if there was a way to tell cordova build to use the .xcworkspace file.

Comment: Well, I think they will support it eventually -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5921

Comment: I also modified their buildscript and swapped out the xcodeproj items with our xcworkspace in the mean time

Comment: It's shocking to find that Cocoapods and Phonegap doesn't work well together. You would imagine that they would be a very common combination.

Comment: I've found that using the Cordova cocoapod actually works fairly well. You still have to have the Cordova project structure, but you lose the Cordova Xcode project, and instead just have it installed as a pod.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi could you give reference to what you edited in the build script to get it to use the xcworkspace instead of the xcodeproj?

Comment: @MikeIsrael, I'm going to attach it to the Jira that I've linked to here, you should be able to retrieve it from there.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi thanks so much I will check it out, also not sure why they downgraded that report, I think it is more than minor and definitely an issue.

Comment: It's probably not a simple change -- and probably a breaking one for them as well. I briefly looked into doing it myself, but got busy (and lazy) and never got around to it. As I mentioned above, using the Cordova CocoaPod works pretty well for us now, though it's completely changed the shape of our project (it's not really a *Cordova* project now, it's a regularly project with Cordova in it).

Comment: What I do in my case is: run cordova prepare ios. And I build directly in xcode. I works for me. But I'd like to have cli way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, after several years, that the short answer to this question is: the default Cordova CLI tools do not properly handle workspaces. There is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5921) to handle this, but as of April 2016, this is not possible by default.

However, you can work around this by using the [Cordova Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Cordova). This does not fix the CLI tools, though.